# Implement multithreading in code contains SQL calls

Tags: perl, perl-module

I want to implement multithreading in my code to reduce time. I implemented Thread::Queue, But I'm getting error Because code contains SQL queries. I'm unable access database through thread at same time.

```
  sub worker{ 
    while($q->queue){
if (exists $href->{$issue}->{'parent'}) {
        foreach my $parent (sort keys %{$href->{$issue}->{'ddts_parent'}}) {
        my $sql_dest1 ="select pkey from jiraissue where ID=(Select Query')";
            my $sth_dest1 = $dbh->prepare($sql_dest1);
            $sth_dest1->execute();

            foreach (my $dest_array = $sth_dest1->fetchrow_array) {
                if ($dest_array ne '') {
------------some code here------------------------------
                        #to retain link between projects and delete Active url.
                        my $remote_key=$dbh->selectrow_array("select Query)");
                        my $temp_ddtsid=$dbh->selectrow_array("select Query')");
                            $jira->update_issue($remote_key,$update);
                        }
                }   
                else {  
                        $jira->update_issue($src_issue,$update);
                    }
                }           
            }
        }       
    } 
    if (exists $href->{$src_issue}->{'ddts_child'}) { 
        foreach my $ddts_child (sort keys %{$href->{$src_issue}->{'ddts_child'}}) { 
            my $sql_dest ="select Query')";         
            my $sth_dest = $dbh->prepare($sql_dest);
            $sth_dest->execute();


            foreach (my $dest_array = $sth_dest->fetchrow_array) {
                if ($dest_array ne '') {

                            $jira->update_issue($src_issue,$update);
                        }
                        #to retain link between projects and delete Active url.
                        my $remote_key=$dbh->selectrow_array("select Query");
                    my $temp_ddtsid=$dbh->selectrow_array("select Query");

        }
    }
```

please give me a solution how to implement multithreading and semaphore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [*Threads and Thread Safety* in the `DBI` documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#Threads-and-Thread-Safety), emphasis mine:

> [When a new thread is created, the whole interpreter with all it's data is cloned.]
>
> However, the internal pointer data within the handles will refer to the DBI and drivers in the original interpreter. Using those handles in the new interpreter thread is not safe, so the DBI detects this and **croaks on any method call using handles that don't belong to the current thread** (except for DESTROY).
>
> Because of this (possibly temporary) restriction, **newly created threads must make their own connections to the database. Handles can't be shared across threads**.
>
> But BEWARE, **some underlying database APIs** (the code the DBD driver uses to talk to the database, often supplied by the database vendor) **are not thread safe**. If it's not thread safe, then allowing more than one thread to enter the code at the same time may cause subtle/serious problems. In some cases allowing more than one thread to enter the code, even if not at the same time, can cause problems. **You have been warned**.
>
> Using DBI with perl threads is not yet recommended for production environments. For more information see http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=288022

To summarize:

- In principle, DBI can work in a multi-threaded environment, as long as the underlying driver is thread safe as well.
- You must create a new connection for each thread. Connections, statement handles, and result handles cannot be shared between threads.

Comment: Thanks amon... Can we use Thread::semaphore to handle these database queries to execute one of after the another? If possible, give a sample example How to implement semaphore. please

Comment: @user3177669 Yes of course we can use `Thread::Semaphore` here, but it isn't useful: Create a new database connection inside each thread. Then each thread can make queries in parallel. The database is responsible for ordering the queries, not your code. However, I'd be surprised if a threaded solution is faster than a non-threaded solution here.

Comment: @user3177669 There is no magical way to make your code suddenly run faster. If you want to optimize, [profile your code](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::NYTProf) first. Then optimize the hot spots to be as efficient as possible. Avoid recalculations and cache whatever you can. Tidy up the code so that you get a better overview. Only when one processor is constantly at 100% while the others are idling can you consider threads, but there are more important optimizations to be performed first.